# LDAP federated users - automatic set Email Verified to true

Tags: configuration, jboss, keycloak

I got the following problem with Keycloak:

I have 2 User Federation modules enabled :

- one is the default **LDAP federation** (internal users)
- one is custom written federation module for Database users (external users)

I also have "Authentication" -> "Required Actions" -> "Email Validate" option enabled (I need email validation enabled for newly registered users).

The problem is that **I need the existing users obtained from the LDAP** (internal users) **to skip email-validation step**, but couldn't find a way to work this around.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you solve this, I'm having the same issue?

Comment: I am really struggling with the same issue... anyone?

Answer (score 9):

I'm definitly late in the party, but in case someone is searching for this in the future.
You can add a mapper in your user federation with hardcoded values. Thanks to @Kvaps for the attribute name.

Here is mine for exemple:
[image: Screenshot]

These are available since 4.8 (not sure) and definitly working on 11.0.0 (my current version)

Answer (score 2):

As an option you can also remove this information from client scope.
This solution is working fine with some applications, eg Kubernetes.

Just go to the **Client Scopes** --> **Mappers**, and remove **email verified** from here.

Now all new bearer tokens will have no `email_verified` field

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way for achieve this right now.

As dirty workaround you can use the next shell-script called by cron:

```
SERVER=http://localhost:8080/auth
USER=admin
PASSWORD=aiPh5ohngai1xoo0eeWa
REALM=master
KCADM=/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh
KEYS="--server $SERVER --realm $REALM --user $USER --password $PASSWORD"

USERS=$($KCADM get users $KEYS | jq -r '.[] | select(.emailVerified == false ) | .id')
for ID in $USERS; do
  $KCADM update users/$ID $KEYS -s emailVerified=true
done
```

This script will find all users with `emailVerified=false` and change value to `true`.

Edit Mode in your LDAP server settings should be set to UNSYNCED or WRITABLE.

---

I really need this feature too, so I've prepared feature request for it:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-8727

Answer (score 1):

Goto ldap configuration page, in advanced settings set option trust email to true. See here >>
[ldap advanced settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Iwpc.png)

Now all the imported users will have email-verified = true

Comment: Thanks, this also works for external Identity Providers, btw (y)